# Plot tweets over time (3min intervals) in R

Tags: r, time, group-by, intervals

I have a dataframe of 3000 tweets in which one of my columns in a time stamp it starts at Mon Apr 27 21:23:22 +0000 2020 and ends at Mon Apr 27 22:48:48 +0000 2020.

What I did now, is extract the hh:mm from the time stamp and grouped by this hh:mm format. However, I would prefer to divide it into 3 minute timeframes in order to make it more clean when plotting the data over time (I think the plot in the image below is a bit to shaky). Can anyone explain how to do this?

In this simple example below the first 4 timestamps should be grouped (21:23 - 21:25), the 4 three should be grouped (21:26 - 21:28), etc.

```
dt <- data.frame(created_at = c("21:23", "21:23", "21:24", "21:25", "21:26", "21:27", "21:27", "21:28"), user_id = c("76389", "83790", "03980", "920", "030", "5345", "653", "25")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example of your data?

Comment: Sure I edited my original post

Comment: Do you have a version that is in `hh:mm` already?

Comment: Yes, I created a column in which I extracted the hh:mm from the time stamp? Would this data be more useful?

Comment: Yes! if you have it already available

Comment: Changed the example code